# How to handle <null> in Json getting crash in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services

In web service i am getting too much < null > values form json response. how to to handle this values ? 
Do i need to check

```
 ex.   [response isEqual:[NSNull null]]
```

everywhere? to avoid crash?. thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the JSON?  That's a URL parameter.

Comment: name post parameter but in json i am getting {"name"=<null>} so get crash.

Comment: That sounds like functionality related to the server, so why post code from the client?

Comment: There are two things you can use

Comment: No idea; I don't know what the crash is, so I don't know how to combat it.

Comment: @trojanfoe I think you should never have your app crash because the server returns something unexpected. The problem may be caused by the server, but this question is about how to not make the app crash.

Comment: I agree, but until we know details of the crash (i.e. the stacktrace) then we cannot help.

Comment: Fair point, but I think a stacktrace is not needed in this case. It seems to me (unless I really missed the point) that the client expects a response from the server with certain keys. If the key has no corresponding value, trying to assign it to a property would crash the client (`property = objectForKey[@"badKey"]`, since you're trying to assign `NSNull`. Simply converting `NSNull` to `nil` and assigning `nil` instead resolves the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call this method on every bit of JSON you're converting to Objective-C. This will either return the right value or return nil. I'm using this as a static method, but you can also make a category on NSDictionary, if you prefer that.

```
+ (id)valueOrNil:(id)value {
    if ([value isMemberOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
        return nil;
    }
    return value;
}
```

Example of how to use this:

```
yourProperty = [YourClass valueOrNil:[json objectForKey:@"yourKey"]];
```

Comment: How is that method easier than simply `value == [NSNull null]`?

Comment: I prefer using `isMemberOfClass` over checking equality with `==` in general, but both should work.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions to that

**First** and important one create a function and call it on each response paring:

```
-(BOOL) isValueOfKeyIsNull(id response){
        if([response==[NSNull null]]){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
}
```

**Secondly**

```
 place try - catch  everywhere so you will no get a crash.
 but still you have to place check where you use the response data.
```

so **First** **Approach** is necessary while doing parsing.

Comment: How is that method easier than simply `value == [NSNull null]`?

Comment: @Danial My response NSDictionary within than multiple value could be <null>

Comment: for dictionary parser you have to do that.
the only thing you can do is 

how to reduce term for condition check for that

responseDictionary[@"key"] this will return value of your required key also you must know the return type of key.
cast the dictionary value of key to that type simple